# While deploying the DSC configuration getting error: "The PowerShell DSC resource X from module Y does not exist at the PowerShell module"

Tags: powershell, dsc

While deploying the DSC configuration I am getting below error:

> InvalidOperation: The PowerShell DSC resource MSFT_AADGroupsNamingPolicy from module <Microsoft365DSC,1.23.726.1> does not exist at the PowerShell module path nor is it registered as a WMI DSC resource.

Checklist:

1. Exported the configuration file from source tenant using Export-M365DSCConfiguration -Components @("AADGroupsNamingPolicy") -Credential $Credential with no issue.
2. Compile the configuration file using .\M365TenantConfig.ps1 -Credential $Credential with no issue.
3. While the deploying the MOF file [Start-DSCConfiguration -Path C:\M365DSC\AADUser\Source\M365TenantConfig\ -Wait -Force -Verbose] getting above error.

Checklist:

1. Update the module.
2. Install the WmiNamespaceSecurity
3. Restart the WMI service in windows.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In the `.ps1` config file, try removing the `-ModuleVersion` parameter from the `Import-DSCResource` cmdlet.